# How to forward an internal IP to an external one?

Tags: routing

A local machine, because of software limitations, needs to connect to a local IP to write to a database. I would like for this machine to write its data to a webserver in the cloud, so I would like to forward the 10.0.0.X IP from our local network to a website, say, mywebsite.net

Can I do this using my router?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, you would use network address translation. You didn't give us any information that can help us tell you what to do, but Googling that term along with the router OS you run should give you enough to get started.

Comment: Let's just say it is a router with a lot of power.

Comment: Telling us how much power it has won't tell us what router it is. You're asking a question that we *cannot* answer in its present form. Which is why jermlac's answer didn't help you even though it is good.

Comment: I am looking for a general way to solve the problem, not a specific one.

Comment: The general way is a 1:1 NAT. If you don't know how to configure one, we can't help you without knowing what router you're using.

Comment: 1:1 will change my internal ip to an external one, i.e 192.168.1.100 to 200.x.x.x  such that if I visit whatismyip.com while on 192.168.1.100 I should see the translation to 200.x

That is not what I want.

I think what I want is an SSL VPN from my router to the external webserver such that any requests made to an internal IP will route over the to the webserver. Thanks anyway.

Comment: 1:1 will also do the opposite, but if you know better then just go ahead and solve the problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a machine inside your firewall to connect to a server on the internet using a different IP address than what your other machines present to the internet.

Most of the time, by default, all workstations on your network will present a single IP address to the internet.  You should look at "1 to 1" nat settings for your firewall or router.  This feature will allow you to assign a new single IP address to a single workstation in your network so that it will send and receive data from a different IP address from the rest of your network.

It would probably help if you post the make and model of your router and firewall.

Also, do you have multiple IP addresses from your ISP?

Comment: I want a machine on my network to make a call to a local IP address, ie 10.0.1.45 and the network to forward that call to mywebsite.net. The router will of course have to backwards translate/keep the connection both ways.

Comment: I will look at the 1to1 NAT settings.

Comment: 1t1 seems like it makes my outgoing request look like the IP of the router, not what I want.